# Refreeze Sherbet

Tags: food-safety

Can you eat Sherbet once it has completely thawed and then frozen again? Mine was left out over night in about 65 degree room. Is it okay to freeze it again and eat it. I put it back in the freezer in the morning.

Comment: Ice cream is not the same stuff it was 50 years ago when they first started experimenting with emulsifiers. The same may be true for sherbet. Freeze it and give it a taste. It may be rife with nasty ice crystals, or it may taste just fine.

Answer (score 4):

While nobody can say with 100% certainty that your refrozen sherbet is safe, I certainly would not expect any danger. The ingredients in sherbet are just not that conducive to quick or dangerous spoilage.

The problem I would anticipate would have much more to do with quality. Sherbet is frozen while being churned, giving it a consistency like ice cream. Since your sherbet was completely thawed and refrozen, it very likely froze in a big chunk. That being the case, you might want to serve it after breaking it up by shaving it with a fork or by using a food processor. Breaking up the ice chunk like that will give you a product that bears very little resemblance to sherbet, but would be more like an Italian ice. Just as good, but different.

Comment: I know this is unlikely helpful for the OP, but if you do happen to have an ice cream maker, you can probably also refreeze it in that and get back closer to the right texture.

Comment: You can also refreeze it as if you were preparing a granita -- pour it into a shallow layer in a pan (eg, a 9x13 casserole dish), and once it starts to freeze, stir it up with a fork.  As it freezes further, every so often scrape the top frozen layer with a fork to break it into smaller crystals.   If you have a blender that can crush ice, you can also freeze it in an ice cube tray and then crush it up in the blender.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the only way to maintain the texture of sherbet melted would be if the sherbet is just slightly thawed. As to restoring completely thawed sherbet, I don't think you can unless you gradually freeze the output from a blender. The Italian ice idea above sounds practical!